# saving output of wavfile generating script on matlab

Tags: matlab, output

I have a wav file generating function and want to save the output of a loop containing this function to a folder as wav files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the function `wavwrite` (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/wavwrite.html) ;-) I hope that helps you and makes it possible for you to save your files.